# Content editor is bugged

Tags: xconnect

I was trying to add some custom contacts to the `XCollect Db` using a scheduler task.

I published my code, then I went to Sitecore. I tried publishing the Scheduler item and suddenly this error is all over my Content.

> ERROR: Calling
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.LoadItem
> method through reflection is not allowed.

[image]

I don't know what's the issue, and even there is no trace of the published code `AddContactswithIdentifier` DLL in the bin folder.

Comment: Check logs and update questions with stack trace.